# swapping given part of array to another part in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am trying to figure out how to move one part of an array into a new part. Consider the following.

```
x = y= np.linspace(-1,1,51)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = X**2 + Y**2

wantToMove = (abs(X)+abs(Y) >= 1) *(X<=0)*(Y<=0)
desiredPlace = (abs(X) + abs(Y) <= 1)*(X>=0)*(Y>=0)
```

I am trying to figure out how to do something that would make `newZ[desiredPlace] = Z[wantToMove]`, (assume `newZ = zeros((Z.shape))` but I cannot figure of the proper indexing to do so

Edit:  when I do newZ[desiredPlace]=Z[wantToMove] , then look at newZ, it just shows a line, which I assume is due to the shape of newZ[desiredPlace[

Comment: `wantToMove` has 325 positive and `desiredPlace` has 276, I think they need to have the same amount of `Trues` to use that syntax

Comment: Yes I see that.  I edited with the correct = added.